# RemoteChannel in a Macro is Stalling

Tags: parallel-processing, metaprogramming, julia

I am trying to find out how to proper way to use RemoteChannel inside of a macro. In a function or the REPL, the following code works:

```
addprocs(3)
r = RemoteChannel(3)
@spawnat(3,put!(r,10))
fetch(r) # Gives 10
```

However, if I put that same stuff in a macro:

```
macro rrtest(src,val)
  quote
    r = RemoteChannel($(esc(src)))
    @spawnat($(esc(src)), put!(r, $(esc(val))))
    println(fetch(r))
  end
end
```

and then call it with the same arguments

```
@rrtest(3,10)
```

then the REPL just stalls. Is there something wrong with using RemoteChannels like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
macro rrtest(src,val)
     quote
       r = RemoteChannel($(esc(src))) #Using a `Future` here maybe be better
       remotecall_wait(r_i->put!(r_i, $(esc(val))), $(esc(src)), r)
       wait(r);
       println(fetch(r))
     end
   end
```

The `wait(r)` should *not* be required -- `fetch` is supposed call `wait` when used on a `Future` or `RemoteChannel`.
But it does seem to be, sometimes.

Changing the `@spawnat` to a `remotecall` means you can pass in the `r`, without that, it gets. I think there are off things with how macro-hygine nests with closures created themself with macros. (`@spawnat`) creates closures inside another macro. It is awkaward to reasonabout.
In general I find `@spawnat` harder to reason about, than `remote_call`.

The reason it needs to be `remotecall_wait` is because otherwise, there is no garentee *when* its contents will run. Which means what is happening to `r` is itself unclear. I feel like it should be safe, but it does not seem to be.
I think because the waiting for `r`, rather than waiting for the `remotecall` that sets `r` is never certain to allow that `remotecall` to run.

#### In Conclusion:

- prefer `remotecall` to `@spawnat`, particularly in macros, for sake of being easier to reason about.
- Sometimes you have to `wait` for things before `fetch`ing them. That is probably a bug
- sometimes waiting for X, when X is to be set by a `remotecall` (or `@spawnat`) returning future Y, requires waiting for Y first. Also probably a bug